# How to Multi Line Git Alias with a Function in ZSH

Tags: git, function, alias, zsh

I'm trying to create a git alias to be able to call `git resquash` from `foo` branch (a child of `master`). The idea is to do a `git rebase -i` from the first commit in that branch without knowing the commit. Something is wrong though. I keep getting errors when trying it out.

Maybe my expansions are wrong? I'm using ZSH.

```
resquash = f() { CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ;\                      
                 COMMONCOMMIT=$(git merge-base ${CURRENTBRANCH} ${1-master}) ;\                      
                 git rebase -i $COMMONCOMMIT }; f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the alias over multiple lines if it is a string with line continuation.  That is, quote it (with double-quotes) and use backslash characters at the line end (don't forget to escape other double-quote characters):

```
[alias]
    test = "!_(){ \
                echo \"Hello\"; \
                echo \"World\"; \
            };_"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why multiline? Why not just one long line? And of course don't forget `!`:

```
resquash = !"f() { CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD); COMMONCOMMIT=$(git merge-base ${CURRENTBRANCH} ${1-master}); git rebase -i $COMMONCOMMIT; }; f"
```

Comment: Multiline to keep formatting with other aliases. Would prefer to avoid wrapping lines. Your line returns ```syntax error : unexpected end of file```